# Sci-fi book about 4 or 5 teenage girls who have powers, published 2000-2008

Tags: story-identification, aliens, young-adult, powers

They have been chosen because they are very intelligent and have powers (seeing the past or the future, being invisible, reading thoughts...) in order to find aliens that are hiding on earth. These aliens look just like humans but they can be identified with their peculiar feet(I think all their toes have the same length or they don't have a curve on the interior side of their feet). I remember that one of the girls was deaf and mute.

The book was published between 2000 and 2008 but not later.